# let headers: HttpHeaders Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

Tags: angular, typescript, http

No logro entender este error, sé lo que significa es muy claro, pero no sé cual es el detonante, por ende les pido ayuda para que me puedan dar ideas y evaluar el motivo del error.

Al importar la librería `HTTPCLIENT` me dice que debo pasar 1 o 2 parámetros pero, necesito pasar 3, anteriormente me ha servido sin ningún problema.

Este es la método en el **services**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

  pageEvent = 0;

  public group = new GroupsSchema;

  urlEndpointb2b = 'https://wegautb2b.herokuapp.com/api/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,fileTransfer: FileTransfer
              ) { }
 
              
  addGroup(token,group):Observable<any> {
    let params =JSON.stringify(group);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                    .set('Authorization', token);
    return this.http.get(this.urlEndpointb2b+'POST_GROUP', params, {headers:headers});
  }
```

El modelo

```
import {MessageSchema} from '../models/message';

export class GroupsSchema{
        user?:string; 
        messages?:[MessageSchema]  
}
```

El error

> let headers: HttpHeaders Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

Comment: `this.http.get` debería ser `this.http.post`. En un GET no puedes enviar nada como cuerpo (body) de la petición

Comment: Gracias Pablo si me acabo de dar cuenta, ya que utilice ese mismo metodo en otro proyecto y me funciono, lo que no me habia dado cuenta era que estaba enviando el metodo get intentado pasarle el objeto. y eso es un post, no un get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método *Get*, no permite obtener 3 parámetros, el *Post* si, ya que se le debe enviar el objeto que es enviado como parámetro.

El cambio fue el *GET* a *POST*.

```
addTopic(token, topic):Observable<any>{
    let params = JSON.stringify(topic);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
                                   .set('Authorization', token);
    return this._http.post(this.url+ 'postRegisterTopic', params, {headers:headers});
}
```